# Mysql pattern recognition and update

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a mysql table - that contains a column of links

like www.example.com/?book=2

how do I select through the entire table - but extract the id, to put it into its own column? A kind of select, update query?

Would it be easier to just copy the column - then force it to an int type? Would that then leave me the id as a number?

What is the best solution for this.

```
SELECT id, sourcelink FROM books

UPDATE books SET id=1 WHERE sourcelink ='www.example.com?book=1';
```

Comment: yes - find the number in the source link - update it in the id coloumn

Comment: Well - the guy below understood what I was asking, despite all of your objections. Thank you Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
update books
    set id = substring_index(sourcelink, '=', -1) + 0
    where sourcelink like '%\?%=%';
```

This sets the `id` to whatever is after the `=` converted to a number.  The `where` clause checks that the `sourcelink` has a structure similar to what you expect.  This is a rather loose pattern.  It could be made more specific by using regular expressions.

Comment: this didn't seem to work

Comment: @TheOldCounty . . . I don't know where those `*` came from.  The correct wildcard is `%`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's worth pointing out or not for future people, just in case... `%` is a wildcard for zero to many characters and `_` is for just one character. [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) will also do [regex](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: Good stuff man. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a mischievous but correct answer, if your `id` number always comes at the end of the text string.

```
UPDATE books
   SET id = CAST(REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(sourcelink) AS INT)) AS INT) AS id  
 WHERE CAST(REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(sourcelink) AS INT)) AS INT) <> 0
```

This relies on the quirk of MySQL's casting of a string to an integer that causes it to understand the string value `99 red balloons` as the integer value 99.